Consistent axis styling for multiple pgfplots positioned in a 3D tikzpicture
I'm working on a tikzpicture that includes a main 3D plot and two additional 2D surface plots positioned within the 3D space. However, I've encountered an issue where the additional plots have differently scaled labels and thinner axis lines compared to the main plot, making them appear disproportionately smaller.
Here's a simplified version of my current LaTeX code using pgfplots:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc,positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Main axis
\begin{axis}[
    name=mainaxis,
    enlargelimits=false,
    axis on top,
    axis equal image,
    axis lines = middle,
    xmin=0, xmax=8,
    ymin=-1, ymax=1,
    zmin=-1, zmax=10,
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, zlabel=$z$,
    view={60}{30},
    % xtick={0, 1, 3, 4},
]

% Coordinates for transformations
\coordinate (O) at (axis cs:0,0,0);
\coordinate (X) at (axis cs:1,0,0);
\coordinate (Y) at (axis cs:0,1,0);
\coordinate (Z) at (axis cs:0,0,1);

% Positions where we want to place the surf plots
\coordinate (P1) at (axis cs:1,0,0);
\coordinate (P2) at (axis cs:3,0,0);

\end{axis}

% Transformation for surf plot at P1
\begin{scope}[shift={(P1)},
    x={($(X)-(O)$)}, y={($(Y)-(O)$)}, z={($(Z)-(O)$)},
    canvas is yz plane at x=0, transform shape]

% Surf plot 1
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    xlabel={$y$}, ylabel={$z$},
    xmin=-1, xmax=1,
    ymin=-1, ymax=1,
    zmin=-1, zmax=1,
    view={0}{90},
    % scale=1,
    xtick={-1,0,1},
    ytick={-1,0,1},
]
\addplot3[
    surf,
    domain=-1:1,
    y domain=-1:1,
    samples=20,
    shader=flat,
    colormap/viridis,
]
({x},{y},{x^2 + y^2});
\end{axis}
\end{scope}

% Transformation for surf plot at P2
\begin{scope}[shift={(P2)},
    x={($(X)-(O)$)}, y={($(Y)-(O)$)}, z={($(Z)-(O)$)},
    canvas is yz plane at x=0, transform shape]

% Surf plot 2
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    xlabel={$y$}, ylabel={$z$},
    xmin=-1, xmax=1,
    ymin=-1, ymax=1,
    zmin=-1, zmax=1,
    view={0}{90},
    scale=1,
    xtick={-1,0,1},
    ytick={-1,0,1},
]
\addplot3[
    surf,
    domain=-1:1,
    y domain=-1:1,
    samples=20,
    shader=flat,
    colormap/viridis,
]
({x},{y},{exp(-x^2 - y^2)});
\end{axis}
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


I aim to have all plots within the tikzpicture — the main 3D axis and the two additional 2D surface plots — share the same font sizes, line widths, tick styles, and overall dimensional consistency.
How can I ensure that the additional pgfplots maintain the same typography and axis styling as the main plot?

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
x={(0.7cm,-0.6cm)}, y={(1.1cm,0.3cm)}, z={(0cm,1.1cm)},
axis lines=center,
xmin=0, xmax=5,
ymin=-1, ymax=1,
zmin=-1, zmax=4,
xlabel=$x$, zlabel=$z$,
]
\coordinate (P1) at (1,0,0);
\coordinate (P2) at (3,0,0);
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
x={(1.1cm,0.3cm)}, y={(0cm,1.1cm)}, z={(0,0)},
anchor=south west, at=(P1),
axis lines=center, hide z axis,
ticks=none,
xmin=-1, xmax=1,
ymin=-1, ymax=1,
axis on top,
]
\addplot3[
surf, shader=flat,
domain=-1:1, y domain=-1:1,
samples=20,
colormap/viridis,
point meta={x^2+y^2},
] (x,y,0);
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
x={(1.1cm,0.3cm)}, y={(0cm,1.1cm)}, z={(0,0)},
anchor=south west, at=(P2),
axis lines=center, hide z axis,
ticks=none,
xmin=-1, xmax=1,
ymin=-1, ymax=1,
axis on top,
]
\addplot3[
surf, shader=flat,
domain=-1:1, y domain=-1:1,
samples=20,
colormap/viridis,
point meta={exp(-x^2 - y^2)},
] (x,y,0);
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


